# How to check null from json string

Tags: iphone, json

When a JSON Response has no data, it will return `Response: [ ]`.

Here is my code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];

    NSString *response =nil;
    if (!error) {
        response = [request responseString];

        NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
}
```

How should I check whether the response has a value or not?

I tried `if([response isEqualToString:@""]|| [response length]==0)` but it is not working. I also tried `if(response == nil);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
if([response isEqualToString:@"[]"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Well...
If the answer when JSON has no answer is [] you could try:

```
if([response isEqualToString:@"[]"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ,

```
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

This one worked for me ..